# Xamarin Forms Iphone 5s. Custom Picker to custom Editor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem only in iphone 5s. When the  focus change from custom control inherited from Picker to one inherited from Editor, the keyboard hide the Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Just use the following code:

```
void Handle_Focused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollStack.ScrollToAsync(labelQuestion, Xamarin.Forms.ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
        }
```